# Why does a value live long enough in loop in a function but not in direct code in tokio::spawn?

Tags: function, rust, borrow-checker

I have some trouble understanding with moved values in loop using tokio:spawn in tokio 0.2. I try to pass a oneshot receiver to a listen function which checks it periodically with a timeout in a loop.

Strangely, this works when I use a separate function `listen` in `tokio::spawn`. However, when I copy the code from that function inside the `tokio::spawn` closure, it does not compile complaining that the value is moved in the previous loop (which I kind of understand). So, why does it work in the function version?

Here is an example for the working version:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::{sync::oneshot, future::FutureExt, timer::delay_for};

pub async fn a() {
    let (stop_sender, mut stop_receiver) = oneshot::channel::<bool>();
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        listen(&mut stop_receiver).await;
    });
    delay_for(Duration::new(1,0)).await;
    stop_sender.send(true).unwrap();
}    

async fn listen(stop_receiver: &mut oneshot::Receiver<bool>) {
    loop {
        match stop_receiver.timeout(Duration::from_secs(1)).await {
            Ok(no_timeout) => match no_timeout {
                Ok(stop) =>
                    if stop {
                        println!("stop signal true received");
                        break;
                    },
                Err(_) => (), // don't stop
            },
            Err(_) => (), // timeout
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    a().await;
    delay_for(Duration::new(2,0)).await;
}
```

The following does not work:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::{sync::oneshot, future::FutureExt, timer::delay_for};

pub async fn b() {
    let (stop_sender, mut stop_receiver) = oneshot::channel::<bool>();
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            match stop_receiver.timeout(Duration::from_secs(1)).await {
                Ok(no_timeout) => match no_timeout {
                    Ok(stop) =>
                        if stop {
                            println!("stop signal true received");
                            break;
                        },
                    Err(_) => (), // don't stop
                },
                Err(_) => (), // timeout
            }
        }
    });
    delay_for(Duration::new(1,0)).await;
    stop_sender.send(true).unwrap();
}    

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    b().await;
    delay_for(Duration::new(2,0)).await;
}
```

When I remove the timeout, it also does not work in the function version (error: moved value in previous iteration of loop). Why is this, i.e. why does it actually work at all in the function version with timeout?
Unfortunately, I cannot figure out an explanation with previous answers on moved values in a loop. Maybe, somebody can explain this. Thanks!

Comment: Your working version has so many mistakes, please add [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: And probably the answer is, you are moving `stop_receiver` with `async move`, you need to borrow( this is the difference with the first one )

Comment: I've added two complete code examples. I still do not understand since in both versions I use async move. Especially if I remove the timeout in version a, it does not work anymore, but why?

Comment: Can you please also tell how do you remove timeout? No need to modify question you can just add on playground.

Comment: Here's the function without the timeout:
```rust
async fn listen(stop_receiver: &mut oneshot::Receiver<bool>) {
    loop {
        match stop_receiver.await {
                Ok(stop) =>
                    if stop {
                        println!("stop signal true received");
                        break;
                    },
                Err => (), // don't stop
            },
        }
    }
}
```